# What does it mean to pass a value through an argument to my program?

Tags: java, arrays, command-line-arguments

I recently made a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62925278/5698098) saying that my code wasn't working and displayed the message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at FactorialProgram5.main(FactorialProgram5.java:11)
```

with the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactorialProgram5 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long n;
        long fact = 1;
        n = 1;
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            n = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
            fact = fact * i;
        }

        System.out.print("fact=" + fact);
    }
}
```

Someone said I have to pass arguments to it and that the array is empty. What does it mean to pass an argument to the code? I am using eclipse, and someone told me that I have to go to the arguments tab and enter a value manually, but I need to make it so I can use this code in the command prompt too. How can I do this?

Comment: "I need to make it so I can use this code in the command prompt too" If you were using the command prompt, you would type the arguments in when you run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main method is what takes any arguments from the command line. For example if you first navigate to the location of your java file on the command line:
Type these commands.
1.`javac filename.java`
this will compile your .java file
2. `java filename` (if you want to run without arguments).
To pass arguments to your file use:
`java filename argument`

Here argument is turned into a String array (args in the main method).

So when this file is compiled an then ran with something like the command
`java filename 99`
the line `n=Long.parseLong(args[0]);` in your code will plug in the number 99 to args[0]. So n will get set to 99, or whatever you decide to type after `java filename` on the command line each time you run this program.

Answer (score 0):

What that guy was talking about is that in the command line you can type in arguments when running the java program, kind of like this:

```
<run-java-using-a-command> Bob Joe Bill
```

I omitted the actual running since that isn't necessary if you're just going to use eclipse. But if you run it like this, then the `args` array will be this:

```
[Bob, Joe, Bill]
```

You can use those arguments in your program. In Eclipse, what you can do is click `Run | Run | Program Arguments` (on the top of the screen) to edit arguments.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you need to add a parameter on the command line so your program will find and process it. The parameter I am using in this example  is the number 3.

I have compiled and run your program on the command line to show how it works.

```
$ javac FactorialProgram5.java
$ java FactorialProgram5 3    
fact=6
$
```

Note: I added a missing newline to the print instruction

```
System.out.print("fact=" + fact);
```

becomes

```
System.out.print("fact=" + fact + "\n");
```